# Passing multiple element changes through a javascript button

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I am new to JavaScript only dabbling in editing rather than creating. I am trying to create a button that when clicked hides the div whilst revealing a hidden div.

I have got this far, and I am pretty sure that the first section is being passed ie.

```
onclick="document.getElementById('page1').style.display='none'";`
```

But not the second

```
"document.getElementById('page2').style.display='block'";
```

FULL CODE

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
         #page1 {
         display: block;
         }
         #page2 {
         display: none;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="page1"> This is page 1
         <button type="button" 
         onclick="document.getElementById('page1').style.display='none'";"document.getElementById('page2').style.display='block'";>link to page 2</button>
      </div>
      <div id="page2"> This is page 2
         <button type="button" 
         onclick="document.getElementById('page2').style.display='none'";"document.getElementById('page1').style.display='block'";>link to page 2</button>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write multiple JS commands in one call, You don't have to put in multiple quotes for this. So all the commands in a single pair of quotes.

```
 <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#page1 {
    display: block;
}
#page2 {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page1"> This is page 1
  <button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('page1').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('page2').style.display='block'";>link to page 2</button>
</div>
<div id="page2"> This is page 2
  <button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('page2').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('page1').style.display='block'";>link to page 2</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: aha, Thank You, :-D Incredible response time. Worked! When I have acumalated enough reputation points I shall Vote you up :D